# Communication between BroadcastReceiver and Activity using interface

Tags: android, interface, broadcastreceiver

Folks!
I'm trying to implement `BroadcastReceiver` for listening to incoming Message using `SMSRetrieverAPI`.

I'm getting messages in Broadcast's `onReceive` method but after that, I have to pass that Message String in activity without restarting it, So I have implemented interface.

I have tried below code but, it throws `NullPointerException` for `mOTPReceiveListener`. Something didn't work perfectly so please correct me.

`SMSBroadcastReceiver` is like below

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

OTPReceiveListener mOTPReceiveListener = null;

public void InitOTPReceiveListener(OTPReceiveListener otpreceivelistener){

    this.mOTPReceiveListener = otpreceivelistener;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

        switch(status.getStatusCode()) {
            case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // Get SMS message contents
                String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                Log.e("VERIFY","Full Message : "+message);

                if (mOTPReceiveListener != null) {
                    String[] temp = message.split("-");
                    String[] msg = temp[1].split(" ");
                    message = msg[0];

                    Log.e("VERIFY","message : "+message);
                    mOTPReceiveListener.onOTPReceived(message);

                }

                break;
            case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                // Waiting for SMS timed out (5 minutes)
                mOTPReceiveListener.onOTPTimeOut();
                break;
        }
    }
}

public interface OTPReceiveListener {
    void onOTPReceived(String otp);

    void onOTPTimeOut();
}
```

}

and the activity code

```
public class VerificationActivity extends BaseActivity implements SMSBroadcastReceiver.OTPReceiveListener
{
    Context mContext;
    Button btn_verify_submit;
    TextView text_resend_otp;

    private String TAG = "VERIFY";

    private String PHONE = null;

    private SmsRetrieverClient mSmsRetrieverClient;
    private SMSBroadcastReceiver mSMSBroadcastReceiver;
    SMSBroadcastReceiver.OTPReceiveListener mOTPReceiveListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verification);

        initView();
        setClickListener();

        PHONE = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
        Log.e(TAG,"phone : "+PHONE);

        mSmsRetrieverClient = SmsRetriever.getClient(this);
        startVerify();

        mOTPReceiveListener = this;
        mSMSBroadcastReceiver = new SMSBroadcastReceiver();
        mSMSBroadcastReceiver.InitOTPReceiveListener(this);

    }

    private void initView()
    {
        layout_verification_main = findViewById(R.id.layout_verification_main);
        overrideFonts(layout_verification_main,VerificationActivity.this);

        edt_verify_code = findViewById(R.id.edt_verify_code);

        btn_verify_submit = findViewById(R.id.btn_verify_submit);

        text_resend_otp = findViewById(R.id.text_resend_otp);
    }

    private void setClickListener()
    {
        btn_verify_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Call OTP Match API

            }
        });

        text_resend_otp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Call Resend OTP API 
            }
        });
    }




    private void startVerify() {
        Task<Void> task = mSmsRetrieverClient.startSmsRetriever();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                Log.e(TAG, "SmsRetrievalResult start onSuccess.");


            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SmsRetrievalResult start failed.", e);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onOTPReceived(String otp) {
        edt_verify_code.setText("" + otp);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Message OTP :  " + otp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("VERIFY","otp in activity : "+otp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOTPTimeOut() {

    }
}
```

and I have registered in Manifest like this

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcast.SMSBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: you are calling this `InitOTPReceiveListener()` in your onCreate() of  activity? that seems wrong

Answer (score 0):

The `SMSBroadcastReceiver` instance created from the definition in your manifest is NOT the same one you created in `VerificationActivity.onCreate()`.

You can register the broadcast receiver from your activity using [`Context.registerReceiver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)).

Answer (score 0):

To contact between activity and receiver what you are try is wrong as your listener is dependent on activities `onCreate()` i.e on lifecycle of Activity.
So to solve this you need to follow below step's:

**Solution**

1. Be sure that activity is alive by starting the activity from your receiver (startActitvity() using intent ) again. check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52174030/7972699) if you don't want to restart the activity again and want to be sure that activity is on screen.
2. Send a broadcast from your receiver to activity read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22241844/7972699). *No need of listener* as activity can directly listen to message

you can combine both solution's for you own use case it will work.